# How many samples should I test to be 95% sure that no error exists?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, descriptive-statistics

If I have a million population of products and I will tolerate no error in them. How many samples should I test to be 95% sure that no error exists?

I am new to statistics. I know you might need some assumptions about distribution. But I do not know much about it. Some make assumptions accordingly and please tell a way in which these can be tested - like how do I know a distribution (if that's required0.

Comment: You need to test the entire population, because no matter how large the sample is or what you assume, there is always a possibility an error exists in any of the untested products.  You might intend a different question that is answerable, such as "how can I have 95% confidence that no more than 1% of the population has errors?"  If so, please edit your post to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

As @whuber said, you can NEVER be 95% sure of 0 defect (i.e. of 100% success), unless you test 100% of the product.
You will need to "accept" a (as small as you desire) amount ot failure.
The distribution you have is a basic binomial; no assumption needed at all (because that is the definition of a binomial).
E.g. to be 95% sure of 95% quality, you need to test 59 samples, and ovbserve no failure. For 99% confidence of 99% quality, that would be come 459 samples (w/o any observed failure), and for 99.9% confidence of 99.9 quality that becomes 6901 test samples (w/o observing aby failure).

Look up binomial distribution, or sampling/testing "by attribute".